# Java Tree Program

Tags: java, tree, substring

I need to create a tree program using Java. I am unable to do this and ran out of ideas. It should use a for-loop and substring. Here is an example for a "sample" string:

```
          S
         SAS
        SAMAS
       SAMPMAS
      SAMPLPMAS
     SAMPLELPMAS
          S
          A
          M
          P 
          L
          E
```

Here is what i have got so far:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userWord, reverse = "";
    int size;

    System.out.print("Enter a word that is less than or equal to 10 characters: ");
    userWord = input.next();

    userWord = userWord.toUpperCase();

    size = userWord.length()-1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= userWord.length() + 1; i++) {
        System.out.print(userWord.substring(0, i));
        System.out.println(userWord.substring(0,i-1));
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Break this down. If you were doing this by hand on a typewriter, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userWord, reverse = "";
    int size;
    StringBuilder padding = new StringBuilder();

    System.out.print("Enter a word that is less than or equal to 10 characters: ");
    userWord = input.next();

    userWord = userWord.toUpperCase();
    reverse = new StringBuffer(userWord).reverse().toString();
    size = userWord.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        padding.append(" ");
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        System.out.print(padding.substring(0, size-i));
        System.out.print(userWord.substring(0, i));
        if(i > 1){
            System.out.println(reverse.substring(size+1-i, size));  //2 >= i  
        }else{
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    String pad = padding.substring(0, size-1).toString();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        System.out.println(pad + userWord.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using one for loop. You would need two. the first would go through the col and then row

```
for (int x = 1; x <= input; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < x; y++)
    {
        System.out.print( // enter what you need here);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Does that make any sense? Let me know if you still have problems

Comment: Why do I need to use two loops? I can get the same result with just one loop.

Comment: @user3281971 the first loop is supposed to transverse through the rows. The second loop is supposed to do the same for the cols. If you're able to do that with only one loop, felicitations, but it wouldn't make sense to me...